# PSQL INSERT INTO with multiple SELECT statements for multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert multiple values from two different tables into my junction table. I found that the below query works, however it means I have to create a full INSERT statement for each row. Is there any way to make this query shorter? E.a. with only one insert statement covering all the select statements. Or even one select statement covering all the values?

```
CREATE TABLE country_x_language
( country_id            BIGINT            REFERENCES country  (id) 
, language_id           BIGINT            REFERENCES language (id)
, PRIMARY KEY  (country_id, language_id)
);

INSERT INTO country_x_language SELECT c.id, l.id FROM country c, language l WHERE c.name = 'Brazil' and l.name = 'Portuguese';
INSERT INTO country_x_language SELECT c.id, l.id FROM country c, language l WHERE c.name = 'Netherlands' and l.name = 'Dutch';
INSERT INTO country_x_language SELECT c.id, l.id FROM country c, language l WHERE c.name = 'Germany' and l.name = 'German';
```

Comment: You can use `OR` in a condition, or `JOIN` against a `VALUES` clause

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use only a single `INSERT` statement with a union of multiple `SELECT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO country_x_language
SELECT c.id, l.id FROM country c, language l WHERE c.name = 'Brazil' AND l.name = 'Portuguese'
UNION
SELECT c.id, l.id FROM country c, language l WHERE c.name = 'Netherlands' AND l.name = 'Dutch'
UNION
SELECT c.id, l.id FROM country c, language l WHERE c.name = 'Germany' AND l.name = 'German';
```

You can also use a single `INSERT` statement with a single `SELECT` statement and more conditions:

```
INSERT INTO country_x_language
SELECT c.id, l.id
FROM country c,
     language l
WHERE (c.name = 'Brazil' AND l.name = 'Portuguese')
   OR (c.name = 'Netherlands' AND l.name = 'Dutch')
   OR (c.name = 'Germany' AND l.name = 'German');
```

But what I would actually recommend is a `VALUES` clause that is `JOIN`ed against the two tables from which you are picking the ids:

```
INSERT INTO country_x_language
SELECT c.id, l.id
FROM (VALUES
 ('Brazil', 'Portuguese'),
 ('Netherlands', 'Dutch'),
 ('Germany', 'German')
) names(country_name, language_name)
JOIN country c ON c.name = country_name
JOIN language l ON l.name = language_name;
```

<sub>([Demo of all the above](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a897869609bce97795827c050d9c4ee9))</sub>